# How to build apk in Android Studio for both amazon app store and google play store with corresponding in-App purchase API

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I would like to build for both Google play store and Amazon app store from the same project created in Android Studio. Since the in-App purchase API is different I will some adjustment right before creating APK for a target store. How can I save time while I switch from one target to another. Some manual process is ok. Following is by gradle source set for google app store.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['app/src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['app/src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['app/src/main/aidl']
        res.srcDirs = ['app/src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['app/src/assets']
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare two gradle `flavour`s for example `googleplay` and `amazon`.

```
   productFlavors {
        googleplay {
            applicationId = '...'
        }
        amazon {
            applicationId = '...'
        }
   }
```

Gradle library dependencies should be different for each `flavour`.

```
googleplayImplementation "...gp_library..."
amazonImplementation "...amazon_dependency..."
```

This way store specific build will not contain another store dependency classes, resources etc.

Then declare interface for example `StoreProvider` which will be enter point for all store specific api calls. In `googleplay` flavour sourceset provide implementation of `StoreProvider` which will call GooglePlay store methods. In `amazon` flavour provide implementation of `StoreProvider` which will call Amazon store methods. Use link to `StoreProvider` interface everywhere in application. If you organize app this way your application will not know anything about what store it uses. Plus it will be easy to add another stores support in the future.